# How to use WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowSize and WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowOrientation

Tags: android, google-chrome-os

I'm puzzled about how to use `WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowSize` and `WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowOrientation` mentioned in the official [Android on ChromeOS guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/window-management#launch_size).

When I use it, it seems like the window is always maximized, e.g. if I set it up like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowSize"
        android:value="phone" />
<meta-data android:name="WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowOrientation"
        android:value="portrait" />
```

If I at the same time specify [`layout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window#layout) for an activity and starts it directly, the window is not maximized anymore.

Does anyone know how the two meta tags can be used? When I google them, the only results is the guide mentioned above and a few other projects using them.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same.  Adding these parameters seems to have no effect on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for a Xamarin context, and with a different meta data option. (Although technique should work for all development environments)

Note the metadata **needs** to be under the Activity element in the AndroidManifest.xml

Using C#/Xamarin one can add the `MetaDataAttribute` to main Activity.

```
[MetaData("WindowManagerPreference:SuppressWindowControlNavigationButton", Value = "true")]

[Activity(Label =...
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

This removes the backbutton from android apps running on chromeos, but has no effect on android apps running on android devices.